# Where is this post method for woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm trying to read the info for the following:

$woocommerce->post(‘products’ , $data);

Thanks for the help.

But I don't get where the "post()" method comes from. I couldn't find any info on the topic through the WC Docs (Rest API) or WP Rest API.

Comment: There is no post() method for WooCommerce… This is a WordPress method: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/requests/post/ or https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_http/post/

Comment: It makes sense now @loictheaztec. thanks.